# Rails `has_many` association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to learning Rails and I'm a bit confused about associations.

Say for example, I have a `Car` which can belong to either a `Owner`, a `Renter` or a `Company` and can only belong to *one* of them and a `Owner`, `Renter` or `Company` can have many `Cars`.

How would you recommend I go about modelling this scenario? Should there be three foreign keys on the `Car` table for `owner_id`, `render_id` and `company_id`? Or have some sort of join table for each of them which would result in something like:

```
| car_id | owner_id |
|--------|----------|
| 1      | 1        |
| 2      | 1        |
| 3      | 1        |
```

Or is there another way to achieve this? While considering that more dependents (more groups of renters, owners etc.) could be added.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic example of where you would use a polymorphic association.

```
class Car
  belongs_to :possessor, polymorphic: true
end


class Owner
  has_many :cars, as: :possessor
end

class Renter
  has_many :cars, as: :possessor
end

class Company
  has_many :cars, as: :possessor
end
```

There are two new fields in the `cars` table, `possessor_type` and `possessor_id` and you can add them with a migration, and you can add other models that might possess a car and there's no need to add more columns to `cars`

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways: make `Car` to have foreign keys on `Owner`, `Renter`, `Company`.

Here is an example.

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner
    belongs_to :renter
    belongs_to :company
end

class Owner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cars
end

class Renter < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cars
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cars
end
```

```
Cars table
id| owner_id | renter_id | company_id |
- |----------|-----------|------------|
1 | 1        | 1         |2           |
2 | 1        | 1         |1           |
3 | 3        | 2         |1           |
```

[The has_many Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)